# UITextField - scroll to left

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating UITextField programmaticaly for taking email addresses to send emails. When user enters multiple email adresses and text becomes longer than the textfield length than as usual text shifts in left side.
But I am not able to scroll to left if I want to edit the first email address I entered.

Here is the code to create Textfield:

```
    let ToTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(140, 150, 500, 40))
    ToTextField.text = "To"
    ToTextField.textColor = UIColor(red:204/255, green:204/255, blue:204/255, alpha:1.0)
    ToTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    ToTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    ToTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    ToTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
    ToTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    ToTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    ToTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    ToTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = .Center
    ToTextField.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    ToTextField.tag=776756
    ToTextField.delegate = self
    self.SendMessageForm.addSubview(ToTextField)
```

Is there any way to make it scroll horizontally left-right direction?

Comment: UITextViewe  is better option for this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview

Comment: What do you mean text "shifts in left side"? You mean the text you're entering at the end of text on the right side causes the input data before move to the left? Have you compared it to the input fields of standard apps distributed with iOS? In other words have you ruled out that it is a gesture you are simply unaware of?

Comment: I agree with @matloobHasnain, you should go with UITextView to accomplish this..Don't use text field if you need scrolling behaviour...

Comment: That is right. The text moves to left and there is no way to go back to the left text at this point without deleting the text. So, need a way to enable it.

Comment: you can go back with log press on textfield without deleting text

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=text+field+editing+ios&rlz=1C5CHFA_enPK717PK718&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=803&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif2bnAhqjRAhXKLcAKHdGrCtUQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=long+press+text+field+editing+ios&imgrc=z4dfcdN09IK2AM%3A

Comment: @dang, you can write a custom textField which is subclass of UIScrolView.